# Application blocked by security settings error on client' Windows8 OS

Tags: java, applet

We are facing this issue on our clients machine.

Our project uses a third party java applet to open the files in respective softwares.
On windows7 we don have any issue but we have issue on windows8 OS

our project is working fine in IE10 and FF browsers. of windows8
this error is thrown only in chrome.

but when we execute same third party demo site which uses this same java applet to open the files in respective softwares, that is working fine in all browsers without making any changes in settings.

I have read many replies from different ppl that we need to changes the client java secutiry settings.
But how can we ask all our clients to make this setting so this is not a proper solution for our problem.
Please see the image below

![Error message][1] is

"Your security system have blocked an application with expired or not yet valid certificate from running"

please help me solve this ..

Comment: From the error message, this sounds like you have to re-sign your JARs with a new trusted certificate.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply and yes we did the same thing and now we don get any error . :)

Comment: @VickyVilas Found any solution? I'm facing same issue.

Comment: @VickyThakor Yes the issue is fixed for us.
Actually we were getting this issue for our third party tool.
We asked for the latest copy from them and then our application started working.

Comment: @VickyVilas Thanks we were facing the same issue..

Answer (score 11):

Go to Control Panel -> Java -> Security -> Edit Site List

Comment: When I go to Control Panel -> Java -> Security the only thing I see is a button that says "Certificates...".

Comment: for windows 7 goto start search for confiure java and click configure java

Comment: You MUST restart Windows after that (although the system won't tell you it). The changes won't apply otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Solution published in my website:
http://www.myerrorsandmysolutions.com/application-blocked-by-security-settings/

1. Go to **Control Panel**
2. **Java**
3. in the **Security** tab click the “**Edit Site List…**” button
4. click **Add** button
5. insert the URL of the website that you want access in (URL should begin with http:// or https://)
6. click **Add** button
7. click **OK** button
8. click **OK** button

Note: you could find an icon Java (32-bit) rather than Java.

If you won’t find in Control Panel a Java icon or the “Edit Site List…” button is missing and you are sure that Java is installed, open a text editor and create a file with name **exception.sites** containing the URL of the website that you want access in (URL should begin with http:// or https://) and save it in the following path:

C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security
where
username
is the name of the user.

Comment: I do not have a "Edit Site List..." button under Security tab. Only button is "Certificates..." (may have been disabled by administrator as i work in a locked down environment). However your exception.sites file worked ! Thanks for that, upvoted.

Comment: Hi, with different version of Windows and Java could happen. I will correct my reply according to your comment. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

go to Control Panel -> Java -> Security , choose minimum security level , Medium(Least secure setting), then click ok , save and try again...

Comment: Medium is no longer available with certain Java versions.