# Your security settings have blocked an application signed with an expired or not-yet-valid certificate from running

Tags: java, security, applet

[Application blocked by security settings error on client' Windows8 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270818/application-blocked-by-security-settings-error-on-client-windows8-os)

I checked above question but it didn't help me so looking for other solution.

Few days back our code signing certificate for applet is expired. We renewed it and I created new jar again and signed this applet with renewed certificate and now I'm getting an exception.

```
com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: Your security settings have blocked an application signed with an expired or not-yet-valid certificate from running
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.showBlockedDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.askUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.validateChain(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByTrustDecider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getTrustedCodeSources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.strategy(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.openClassPathElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I removed all existing certificate from Java Control Panel and I open our website where I'm getting new certificate details in applet. Latest expiry date but when I click on `Run` its throwing an exception.

[image]

I checked Java Control Panel again then its showing old certificate why new certificate is not used by Java?

[image]

Comment: Remove the old one from the control panel then add the new one ..

Comment: I removed from control panel and launched applet again but not worked. In control panel it shows old certificate.

Answer (score 9):

Essentially you'll have to re-sign your JARs within your deployed ear/war with a new trusted certificate. Until then there are workarounds, There are two things you can do here:

1. Goto Control Panel -> Java -> Security -> Edit Site List

Add you application url, wildcards are accepted. Kindly note that you might have to close the browser and start again, to be able to read the new configuration.

2. In the java control panel security tab, reduce the security level to medium, apply, ok and restart your browser. It should work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create file in the user's home directory:

```
/usr/home/username/.java/deployment/security/security/exception.sites
```

Add the sites that should be given exception.

```
https://192.168.70.10
```

But if you prefer a GUI application, run `JControl` and create exception site list.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the website in Trusted sites in JAVA

Control Panel - JAVA - Security Tab or on Home screen you will see the option to add the website.

Once you add the website you will get security pop ups just select allow or yes and your error will be fixed.