# Signed and timestamped JAR not working after expiry

Tags: java, jar, timestamp, signing, jar-signing

I signed a JAR with a certificate from third party and also time stamped it.
Now the certificate has expired, but since the JAR is timestamped at a time when 
the certificate is still active and also since the JAR is not modified after that
should'nt the JAR continue to work even after the certificate is expired?
Instead I get the following message

[image]

Can I get some help here?

Comment: If the cert is invalid it shouldnt work. You can try to lower/edit your security settings

Comment: @Goot the certificate is not 'invalid', it has expired but since the JAR was timestamped when it was signed, it should continue to work

Comment: As I understand this depends on your security settings

Answer (score 0):

Was the certificate revoked? As noted [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/code_signing_understanding_who_and), timestamps for revoked certificates are not considered due to uncertainties in the actual date of the compromise.

If this is not the case, it may be worth looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270818/application-blocked-by-security-settings-error-on-client-windows8-os) which appears to deal with the same issue.

Comment: No the certificate is not revoked.